Analyzing misaligned rows in Excel in a Pivot Table
I have a recurring dataset which consists of two lists of document counts by source and date. I need to compare the totals and identify any discrepancies. A pivot table works well for this purpose when the sources and dates match. However, the dataset does not include zero values - if a given source and date has no documents, that row is not included. This results in the two lists being of unequal column length and the pivot table fails to compare the correct rows.
How can I programmatically compare equivalent rows, and either add in zero rows to keep the column lengths the same or otherwise ensure that all rows are properly lined up?
I tried to iterate over the column and add blank entries as needed. However, because there is no programmatic way that I can think to tell which of the two lists is missing a row when the sources and dates aren’t the same, I have not been able to consistently insert the zero entry in the right list and location.

Pretty much impossible to suggest anything when you've not provided any example of what your actual data looks like.  Could you do it manually by inspecting the data?  If No, then it's possible there's also no way to do it using VBA.

I am able to do it manually, but I’m struggling to translate that to a program. When I scan through the data, I can see which columns are misaligned, but there’s not a clear rule to identify which list is missing an entry.

If you're able to do it manually then it can be automated, but you'd first need to describe exactly what the manual steps are.  There's no way for us to know how you'd do it.

...writing out the manual steps should help you with figuring out some logic for a VBA solution

You can compare 2 lists without them being of equal length, eg with a dictionary object
